# Como solucionar los espacios en blanco de un header?

Tags: php, html, html5, css3

necesito ayuda con un pequeño problema que tengo en la creación de un index. En la siguiente imagen, no se como rellenar de manera completa el fondo (que no queden espacios) ¿Como lo puedo solucionar? disculpen mi ignorancia, que soy nuevo en esto aún u.u

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Podrías compartir parte de tu código, tanto HTML y CSS, es imposible ayudarte si no conocemos la estructura de tu sitio

Comment: Puede ser que toda la página genere ese espacio en blanco a la derecha?

Comment: El código va como texto, además se requiere también el HTML